# Hyperlink color on Unix & Linux is too subtle on Chrome

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks

When I visit [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), I can barely tell when someone has included a hyperlink. Just today I could tell from context that a user had included a link in the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/374220/238000), but until hovering over it with my mouse I wasn't sure which word(s) were part of the hyperlink.

The contrast is pretty poor in Chrome, but reasonably bad in Firefox and Internet Explorer. For me it gets even worse when I'm not facing the screen exactly straight; even the difference between my eye level and the top of the screen makes it noticeably more difficult to distinguish between normal text and hyperlinks.

I realize that [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137438/361960) question already discusses this topic in general across all Stack Exchange sites (and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66658/hard-to-pick-up-hyperlinks-in-answers) one asks in a really vague way), but I wanted to bring this up in the context of [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) specifically since that's the place where it's been the biggest issue for me. I've never had too much of an issue on other Stack Exchange sites.

P.S. I'm currently on Windows 7 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes. This is indeed an issue. It's even worse in our chat rooms.

Comment: @terdon you're an administrator, do you also develop code for Unix & Linux ? If not, can you bring this to light of developers so that, colors of links on Unix & Linux can be made orange just like here in meta. It is distinctly visible. But one more thing I'd like to mention is that I am saying this as I am not color blind. I don't know if it would be harder for color blind people to distinguish blue color in Unix & Linux or orange color in Meta Unix & Linux

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut I'm not an administrator! I'm just a regular schmuck, like you, who's been elected to serve as a moderator. I don't work for Stack Exchange and I am not affiliated with Stack Exchange in any way. Sorry :(

Comment: Okay @terdon , I'm tagging Jeff Atwood here then

Comment: @JeffAtwood just wanted to bring this to your attention

Comment: Uhm. Jeff hasn't been working with SE for a few years now and, even if he were still around, only people who have interacted with a post get notified by `@username`. The SE developers watch the local metas, so this has already been communicated to them. However, it is (naturally) not a very pressing bug, so I doubt it will be high in their list of priorities.